# Why does LINQ to SQL generate multiple select queries?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, sql-server-profiler

I am using LINQ2SQL. I just noticed (in the SQL Profiler) that LINQ was generating multiple select statements for the below LINQ

> var tableData =
>   dataContext.*TableName*.ToList();

The SQL profiler shows the below DML statements twice

> Select *columnNames* from *TableName*

What is the reason for this?

Comment: @Miral: I took the liberty to edit your question into an actual question, as well as editing the tags. Please review it and change it if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: Are you sure it actually executed the query twice? The first time might have been just a prepare or syntax check (SET PARSEONLY)

Comment: I checked multiple times, yes its generating the select statement twice

Comment: Thanks for changing the question and tags

Comment: Does it do this for a very simple console exe just doing to one thing? (create a data-context, get the data into a list)

Comment: @Ryk - I'm not sure that is true at all; I have (almost-)full control over my LINQ code, what is executed and when. However, without a full repro it is still impossible to know in this case.

Comment: @Marc G - he he, almost. If you have a transactional system, 'alsmost' is as good as none. But as I said, LINQ has its place and I am not against it, I wont pull a car trailer with a truck, and I wont pull a truck trailer with my car, get my drift.... Horses for courses.

Comment: @Ryk - and when LINQ doesn't suit, I just drop to TSQL via Execute*...

Comment: @Marc G - exactly my point. If the purpose fits, do it. The most dangerous thing any developer can do is to have one methodology to do 'X' and they all the other scenarios has to fit his methodology. I say no, explore, use everything, and see how every technology and framework fits each situation, and then start using the right framework/technology for the places you find it works best!

Answer (score 9):

The query *as presented* will do exactly one select statement. I wonder if the problem here is hidden in moving the question to a simple example. Most likely in the *actual* code it doesn't push the data into a list. Methods like `.Where()` only *compose* a ***query*** - it doesn't load the data into a list, so the following is 2 queries:

```
var tableData = dataContext.TableName.Where(row => row.Foo == bar);
foreach(var items in tableData) {...}
foreach(var items in tableData) {...}
```

Adding a `.ToList()` will force it to buffer in memory in a single TSQL query; subsequent enumeration over the list will be done in memory (LINQ-to-Objects).

Of course, you can profile what LINQ-to-SQL is executing pretty simply:

```
dataContext.Log = Console.Out; // or any other text-writer
```

Comment: I think that is what he is doing actually. His problem apparently is that the .ToList() method is calling twice to the data base.

Comment: @vtortola and when I see a repro, I'll believe that

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server Profiler subscribes to the following events by default;

```
Audit Login
Audit Logout
Existing Connection
RPC:Completed
SQL:BatchCompleted
SQL:BatchStarting
```

If you start the profiler with these default events you see every batch statement repeated 2 times just because of `SQL:BatchStarting` and `SQL:BatchCompleted` events. It is a common misconception that worth to be checked.